# How do I have to config my pc to view pdf documents in SAP Logon?

Tags: pdf, ascii, sap-erp, sap-gui

I have two pcs with the same SAP Logon version. Initially they have the **same configuration** but in one of them I can view correctly the pdf documents but in the other pc I only see ascii-chars. Obviously they don't have the same config, but I can't see which changes in the configuration pc I have to do to fix the issue.

Although the following images you can see different documents, the error is the same for all pdf documents.
I don´t have any problem to see other type of documents (.txt, .jpg...) The problem is with pdf documents.
Did someone else have this issue and do you know how to fix?

[image]

Comment: No idea, if that could be the reason, but is Adobe Acrobat Reader implemented on the PC, where it does not work?

Comment: the pic is too small, nothing can be recognized

Comment: What transaction code do you use to display this data? Is the file assigned a Content-Type/MIME type in SAP? I guess that the PDF is displayed using a Web browser control and the Windows Registry is different for Content-Type in both laptops. Note that your screenshots would be better if they try to show the same document. (and be careful to obfuscate addresses in the text screenshot)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Adobe Acrobat Reader are installed in both pcs. @SandraRossi thank you for your recomendation - I've just changed the image. I will review the registry.